# I'm stuck with this query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In this query I want to insert the associative array elements output that prints a phone number separated into three columns in table `phonebook` and insert this output into this table.

```
CREATE TABLE Phonebook 
(
      areacode  VARCHAR2(3),
      prefix    VARCHAR2(3),
      num   VARCHAR2(4)
);

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    TYPE phone_num IS RECORD (
     arac Phonebook.areacode%TYPE, prf Phonebook.prefix%TYPE, recnum phonebook.num%TYPE); 

    TYPE phonenum IS TABLE OF phone_num INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    aaaray phonenum;
    aaaray2 phonenum;

    CURSOR c IS 
    SELECT phone_number 
    from employees
    where department_id IN (20,80,90);
    diff INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    for i in c loop
    diff := diff + 1;
    IF  SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '011' then 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('International');

    ELSIF  SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '515' then 
    aaaray(diff).arac := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).prf    := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).recnum       := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('phone number is domestic ' || aaaray(diff).arac || aaaray(diff).prf || aaaray(diff).recnum);
    elsif SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '603' then
    aaaray2(diff).arac := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
    aaaray2(diff).prf    := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
    aaaray2(diff).recnum       := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('phone number is domestic ' || aaaray2(diff).arac|| aaaray2(diff).prf || aaaray2(diff).recnum);
else 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no display');
end if;  
end loop;
insert into Phonebook values (aaaray.arac, aaaray.prf, aaaray.recnum) ;

   insert into Phonebook values (aaaray2.arac, aaaray2.prf, aaaray2.recnum) ;
END;
/
```

ERROR:

> Error report
>   ORA-06550: line 39, column 66:
>   PLS-00302: component 'RECNUM' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 39, column 66:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
>   ORA-06550: line 39, column 4:

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert array in Phonebook table.

Replace following:

```
insert into Phonebook values (aaaray.arac, aaaray.prf, aaaray.recnum) ;
insert into Phonebook values (aaaray2.arac, aaaray2.prf, aaaray2.recnum) ;
```

with

```
For diff in 1..aaaray.count loop
     insert into Phonebook values (aaaray(diff).arac, aaaray(diff).prf, aaaray(diff).recnum) ;
     insert into Phonebook values (aaaray2(diff).arac, aaaray2(diff).prf, aaaray2(diff).recnum) ;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your insert statement inside for loop. As I can see you are not doing anything else with your collects variables apart from storing the data, You may use only 1 variable also -

```
DECLARE
    TYPE phone_num IS RECORD (
     arac Phonebook.areacode%TYPE, prf Phonebook.prefix%TYPE, recnum phonebook.num%TYPE); 

    TYPE phonenum IS TABLE OF phone_num INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    aaaray phonenum;

    CURSOR c IS 
    SELECT phone_number 
    from employees
    where department_id IN (20,80,90);
    diff INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    for i in c loop
    diff := diff + 1;
    IF  SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '011' then 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('International');

    ELSIF  SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '515' then 
    aaaray(diff).arac       := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).prf        := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).recnum     := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('phone number is domestic ' || aaaray(diff).arac || aaaray(diff).prf || aaaray(diff).recnum);
    INSERT INTO Phonebook VALUES (aaaray(diff).arac, aaaray(diff).prf, aaaray(diff).recnum)) ;
    elsif SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '603' then
      aaaray(diff).arac     := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
      aaaray(diff).prf      := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
      aaaray(diff).recnum   := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('phone number is domestic ' || aaaray(diff).arac|| aaaray(diff).prf || aaaray(diff).recnum);
      INSERT INTO Phonebook VALUES (aaaray(diff).arac, aaaray(diff).prf, aaaray(diff).recnum) ;
    else 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no display');
    end if;
  end loop;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes that can simplify and speed things up.
Specifically, use the `Phonebook` table itself to define your records, and use `FORALL` syntax and record-based inserts.

Here's the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Phonebook 
(
      areacode  VARCHAR2(3),
      prefix    VARCHAR2(3),
      num   VARCHAR2(4)
);
create table Employees
(
      employee_id number,
      name varchar2(100),
      department_id number,
      phone_number varchar2(30)
);
insert into employees values(1, 'George Washington', 20, '515-123-4567');
insert into employees values(2, 'Harry Truman', 20, '603-123-4567');
insert into employees values(3, 'Andrew Jackson', 80, '313-123-4567');
insert into employees values(4, 'Millard Fillmore', 90, '011-12-34567890');

commit;
```

Replace the definition of the record type in your code with a reference to the table itself:

```
    -- no need to define the record before, just use phonebook%rowtype
    TYPE phonenum IS TABLE OF phonebook%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    aaaray phonenum;
    aaaray2 phonenum;
```

Fix up the references to the record columns to match the target table

```
    aaaray(diff).arac       := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).prf        := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).recnum     := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );
...becomes...
    aaaray(diff).areacode  := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).prefix    := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).num       := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );
```

And replace the `INSERT` statements with `FORALL` wrapping `INSERT` of full records:

```
forall i in aaaray.FIRST..aaaray.LAST
  insert into Phonebook values aaaray(i);
forall i in aaaray2.FIRST..aaaray2.LAST
  insert into Phonebook values aaaray2(i);
```

The `FORALL` keyword causes Oracle to get the full list of inserts ready and then send them to the database in one shot rather than doing a context switch for each record. This is much more efficient.
Because we defined the records based on the table, we can insert them directly without needing to reference fields individually.

This makes life so much easier if the table has dozens of fields.

Here's the full modified version of your code:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE phonenum IS TABLE OF phonebook%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    aaaray phonenum;
    aaaray2 phonenum;

    CURSOR c IS
    SELECT phone_number 
    from employees
    where department_id IN (20,80,90);
    diff INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    for i in c loop
    diff := diff + 1;
    IF  SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '011' then 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('International');

    ELSIF  SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '515' then 
    aaaray(diff).areacode  := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).prefix    := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
    aaaray(diff).num       := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('phone number is domestic ' || aaaray(diff).areacode || aaaray(diff).prefix || aaaray(diff).num);
    elsif SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 ) = '603' then
    aaaray2(diff).areacode := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 1, 3 );
    aaaray2(diff).prefix   := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 5, 3 );
    aaaray2(diff).num      := SUBSTR (i.phone_number, 9, 4 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('phone number is domestic ' || aaaray2(diff).areacode|| aaaray2(diff).prefix || aaaray2(diff).num);
else 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no display');
end if;  
end loop;
forall i in aaaray.FIRST..aaaray.LAST
  insert into Phonebook values aaaray(i);
forall i in aaaray2.FIRST..aaaray2.LAST
  insert into Phonebook values aaaray2(i);
END;
/
```